# Correspondence between inductively definable and countable

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory

Working within ZFC:

Is the collection of all countable sets (call it $C$) a well-defined set, or is it a proper class? If $C$ is a set, I would suspect it's at least uncountable. For example the elements of $P(\mathbb{N})$, the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, are countable and hence are elements of $C$ (i.e. $P(\mathbb{N})\subseteq C$). The presence of an uncountable subset in $C$ would imply that $C$ itself is uncountable, no?

Similarly, is the collection of all inductively-definable sets (call it $I$) a well-defined set or is it a proper class? Here, one can take "inductively-definable" to be same concept laid out in *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* by Enderton (see **section 1.4**). If $I$ is a set, is it countable or uncountable?

I suspect that there is a bijective correspondence between the collections $C$ and $I$. Hence, I would anticipate $I$ must be uncountable as well. For if $I$ were countable, the aforementioned bijection would be between a set which is uncountable and a set which is countable; this would be nonsensical. But does such a bijection exist to begin with, and if so how can we formalize this correspondence? In particular, is it the case that a set is inductively-definable iff it is countable?

Comment: $C$ is a proper class, since $\{x\}$ is finite (hence countable) for every set $x$. However, the set of *hereditarily* countable sets is a well-defined set, and is denoted as $H_{\omega_1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the collections you mention are proper classes. If the collection of countable sets were a set, then the collection of finite sets would be set. But the latter collection is a proper class. If the collection of inductive sets (in the sense of Enderton) were a set, then the collection of limit ordinals would be a set (since limit ordinals contain the empty set and are closed under ordinal successors). However, the latter collection is a proper class as well.